# jQuery.load causes mixed content warning (when all content is secure)

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl

I have 2 pages on the same server that are both secure and the SSL badge (*the lock in the address bar on Chrome, not a badge on the site footer*) works fine on each when the pages are viewed individually.

However, when one of the pages loads the other page into a `<div>` via `$('.my-element').load('the_url');` the lock in the address bar gains a yellow caution triangle that informs you there is mixed content when you click on it.

There is no popup message displayed but this is still undesired.

This isn't just happening in Chrome, it is in all browsers.

I tried using a relative and absolute URL to load the page with.

Also both pages are completely secure and this only happens after the load completes.

Any idea what the cause is or how to prevent?

Comment: Are there any iframes on either?

Comment: @liho1eye No there is not, it loads the content directly into a div via `$.load()` and there is no iframes used anywhere on the page.